# Number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length error in a matrix of list

Tags: r, list, matrix

I'm trying to replace a value in a matrix of list with a longer list.

For example,

```
a <- matrix(list(0),nrow = 5, ncol=5)
a[1, 1] <- append(a[1, 1], list(c(1,1))
```

This gives me an error:

```
Error in a[1, 1] <- append(a[1, 1], list(c(1, 1))) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I'm aware that I can try to create a list like this:

```
a <- matrix(list(0),nrow = 5, ncol=5)
a[1, 1] <- list(append(a[1, 1], list(c(1,1)))
```

However, the problem is I wouldn't be able to loop this in a for loop. I'm looking for a way to append the list such that it can be looped and consists of one list like:

```
a[1,1] <- c(list(0), list(1,1))
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This looks like bad design. But maybe `a[1, 1] <- list(append(a[1, 1][[1]], list(c(1,1))))`?

Comment: What is your intended output?  And `a <- matrix(list(0),nrow = 5, ncol=5)`  Why the `list(0)` parameter when a simple `0` will do?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I'm trying to create a recursive matrix M(i,j) = (c(M(i-1,j-1), 1), c(M(i-1,j-2), 2), ..., c(M(i-1,j-5),5))  if that makes sense... If using a matrix of list is a bad design, do you have any suggestion for making this possible?

Comment: I found a way to use Roland's solution to create a recursive matrix! But it was actually ```a[1, 1] <- (append(a[1, 1][[1]], list(c(1,1)))``` Thank you!